# A projectile in a rocket with constant proper acceleration

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, acceleration, coordinate-systems, projectile

I am a beginner in general relativity. I read the chapter 9.2 in Relativity make relatively easy vol 1 by Andrew Steane.

There is a rocket which accelerates upwards with constant proper acceleration. The worldlines of the rocket frame should be hyperbolas. A rocket observer throws a ball in the rocket, the ball should go upwards and then fall down then he mentioned the worldline of the thrown ball looks a vertical straight line. However, I totally do not understand why the worldline of the ball is a vertical straight line.

The whole description is like the following picture.

[image]

The brown one is the vertical worldline of the thrown ball. That is what I am confused of. The red hyperbolas are the worldlines of the rocket frame. The two blue slant lines are asymptotes of rocket frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates represented by the axis belong to an inertial frame. For this frame, all the hyperbolas are accelerated frames, which are momentarily at rest in $t=0$, separated by the distances corresponding to the interception with the x-axis.

If an object is free from its accelerated frame exactly at $t=0$ and without relative velocity with respect to this frame, its worldline is vertical.

In a more general situation it is a straight line, with an angle proportional to the initial velocity with respect to the inertial frame which made the chart.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am inspired by your reply.